# how to display 2011-01-27-123907 instead of 20110127123907 (php)

Tags: php

what is the easiest way of

displaying string **2011-01-27-123907** 
instead of **20110127123907**

without writing special function for it?

Comment: Need moarr details! is that a date? or a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
echo date('Y-m-d-His',strtotime('20110127123907')); // Output: 2011-01-27-123907
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$d = date('Y-m-d-His')
```

For more formatting tips, check [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)